# Excel VBA: "Like" Incorrectly Returns True and False with Chr 35

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to employ a conditional statement in a larger project that triggers when a number is followed by a pound/hash sign (#).  It wasn't working in the project so I made a simple test and obtained strange, counter-intuitive results.

Could someone share why the first MsgBox statement here returns true and the second returns false?  And also, how do I accurately return true when there is a number followed by the "#" sign?

```
Sub Testing()

Dim mystring As String

    mystring = "43"
        MsgBox mystring Like "#" & Chr(35) 'Returns True

    mystring = "43#"
        MsgBox mystring Like "#" & Chr(35) 'Returns False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain characters must be escaped:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator

> To match the special characters left bracket ([), question mark (?),
>   number sign (#), and asterisk (*), enclose them in brackets. The right
>   bracket (]) can't be used within a group to match itself, but it can
>   be used outside a group as an individual character.

```
? "3#" like "#[#]" '>> True
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware characters still needed to be escaped if you used the character code.

Comment: Whether you use `#` or `Chr(35)` it's the same character in the end.

Comment: Thanks again, Tim!